# adding elements in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i am working on a node js project in there i have to add some elements in a array object. i had figure out one way , it has a problem. it can't work with duplicate name's.

hare is the code

```js
let arrayObject = [
  { name: "l2k", killPoint: 10 },
  { name: "l2kb", killPoint: 6 },
  { name: "gd", killPoint: 0 },
  { name: "l2kb", killPoint: 5 },
  { name: "gd", killPoint: 0 },
  { name: "l2k", killPoint: 4 },
  { name: "gd", killPoint: 0 },
  { name: "l2k", killPoint: 1 },
];

//conver ter using
let winCount = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

let pointsystem = [12, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0];
const positionAdd = (objects) => {
  const posRes = {};
  let i = 0;
  objects.forEach(({ name, killPoint }) => {
    posRes[name] = posRes[name] || {
      name,
      win: 0,
      positionPoint: 0,
      killPoint: 0,
    };
    posRes[name].win = winCount[i] || 0;
    posRes[name].positionPoint = pointsystem[i] || 0;
    posRes[name].killPoint = killPoint;
    i += 1;
  });
  return Object.values(posRes);
};
console.log(positionAdd(arrayObject));
```

output getting

```js
[
    { name: 'l2k', win: 0, positionPoint: 3, killPoint: 1 },
    { name: 'l2kb', win: 0, positionPoint: 7, killPoint: 5 },
    { name: 'gd', win: 0, positionPoint: 4, killPoint: 0 }
]
```

output expected

```js
  [
    { name: "l2k",  win: 1, positionPoint: 12, killPoint: 10 },
    { name: "l2kb", win: 0, positionPoint: 9, killPoint: 6 },
    { name: "gd",   win: 0, positionPoint: 8, killPoint: 0 },
    { name: "l2kb", win: 0, positionPoint: 7, killPoint: 5 },
    { name: "gd",   win: 0, positionPoint: 6, killPoint: 0 },
    { name: "l2k",  win: 0, positionPoint: 5, killPoint: 4 },
    { name: "gd",   win: 0, positionPoint: 4, killPoint: 0 },
    { name: "l2k",  win: 0, positionPoint: 3, killPoint: 1 },
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your function doesn't work is you're creating an object for `posRes` with the keys being the `arrayObject.name`

This will only output 3 items in the object since you only have 3 unique names in the array.

I reworked your `positionAdd` function so it's not using `forEach` and saving to an object, but instead just creating a new array by using `.map()` and it gives the expected result:

```js
const positionAdd = (objects) => {
  const posRes = objects.map(({ name, killPoint }, idx) => ({
    name,
    win: winCount[idx] ?? 0,
    positionPoint: pointsystem[idx] ?? 0,
    killPoint,
  }));
  return posRes;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Something more like:

```js
let arrayObject = [
  { name: "l2k", killPoint: 10 },
  { name: "l2kb", killPoint: 6 },
  { name: "gd", killPoint: 0 },
  { name: "l2kb", killPoint: 5 },
  { name: "gd", killPoint: 0 },
  { name: "l2k", killPoint: 4 },
  { name: "gd", killPoint: 0 },
  { name: "l2k", killPoint: 1 },
];
let winCount = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let pointsystem = [12, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0];


const positionAdd = (objects) => 
  objects.map((obj, index)=>
    ({...obj, win: winCount[index] || 0, positionPoint: pointsystem[index] || 0})

console.log(positionAdd(arrayObject));
```

So we `map` over the array, keeping each element in its position and adding the relevant `winCount` and `pointsystem` values as needed, based on the index of the object.

Point of OCD, if you're going to camelCase `winCount`, be consistent: `pointSystem`.